# Configuration a river for MongoDb collection indexed from ES

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mongo-river

I am trying to insert data in MongoDb and view it on ES

```
  > show collections
   person
   system.indexes
  > var p = {firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith"}
  > db.person.save(p)
  WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
  > db.person.find()
  { "_id" : ObjectId("55e43765b1bf54d157542009"), "firstName" : "John",    "lastName" : "Doe" }
  { "_id" : ObjectId("55e43b7e245babbe4052f55b"), "firstName" : "John", "lastName" : "Smith" }
```

The data in mongo db is in db : testmongo     collection: person

Now ,
when I do

```
  curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_river/mongoindex/_search?q=firstName:John'
```

I get

```
{"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

but on browser when I type

```
 http://10.130.10.121:9200/_river/_search?pretty
```

I get

> {
>     "took" : 1,
>     "timed_out" : false,
>     "_shards" : {
>       "total" : 5,
>       "successful" : 5,
>       "failed" : 0
>     },
>     "hits" : {
>       "total" : 2,
>       "max_score" : 1.0,
>       "hits" : [ {
>         "_index" : "_river",
>         "_type" : "mongodb",
>         "_id" : "_meta",
>         "_score" : 1.0,
>         "_source":{"type": "mongodb", "mongodb": {"db": "testmongo","collection": "person"},"index": {"name": "mongoindex", "type": "person"}}
>       }, {
>         "_index" : "_river",
>         "_type" : "mongodb",
>         "_id" : "_status",
>         "_score" : 1.0,
>         "_source":{"error":"NoClassSettingsException[Failed to load class with value [mongodb]]; nested: ClassNotFoundException[mongodb]; ","node":{"id":"NrkM50zoS1OX5IajaPdavw","name":"Redsand1","transport_address":"inet[/172.17.0.2:9300]"}}
>       } ]
>     }
>   }

Please help me get proper data in ES index from MongoDb on browser

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem of version compatibility. So I uninstalled everything and used 
ES version 1.4.2
Mongo Db version 3.0.6
Mapper attachment version 2.4.3
elasticsearch-river-mongodb 2.0.9
And everything worked fine for me